# Perl-compatible regular expression to select everything except second word

Tags: regex, perl, drupal, pcre

I'm trying to use a PCRE that selects everything EXCEPT the first string of numbers in a line of text. The number string can be 3, 4, or 5 digits long, but is always the second word after article. Here are some examples:

> article 11367 airline experts incheon airport transfers operational expertise indonesia
>
> article 8364 future investment korean government invest 4 trillion won science technology ict rd
>
> article 2151 fighter procurement lockheed martin able propose lower prices f 35s

I am currently using the expression `\b(?=\w*[a-zA-Z])\w+\b`. This selects everything but the numbers. This is almost perfect, but as you can see in lines 2 and 3 above, sometimes numbers occur after the first set. I want to select every word except the second, or ignore the first set of numbers but include the others, so that in the end the matched result looks like this:

> article airline experts incheon airport transfers operational expertise indonesia
>
> article future investment korean government invest 4 trillion won science technology ict rd
>
> article fighter procurement lockheed martin able propose lower prices f 35s

I'm doing this because the Drupal module search404 includes a PCRE string in its configuration that selects everything you want to *eliminate* from the search string. It also includes a function to automatically conduct a custom search URL with the search terms, and lets you construct the URL. I want to construct the URL so that it looks like /node/number, which will automatically send the user from the old article URL (one of the lines above) to the new article URL.

Comment: How are these strings getting into the URL in the first place? Do they really contain spaces (encoded as `%20`)?

Comment: the URL is processed before it gets to the regex and by the time that happens the spaces are not encoded, they are just spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

If you are sure numbers come in second position then make use of `\K`.

```
^\S+\s+|\G(?!^)\d+\K|\G(?!^).*$
```

Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3mH8/3

---

#### Original  post

If you are sure numbers come in second position then make use of `\K`.

```
^\S+\s+\K\d+
```

Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3mH8/1

Comment: That will remove just the digits, which is the only part the OP wants to keep

Comment: i'm trying to accomplish the exact opposite of this. don't select numbers, select everything else.

Comment: If it worked, +1. Working answers should never be downvoted, and accepted answers must not be downvoted BY DESIGN.

Comment: @stribizhev: The downvote is mine, and it is because the original form of this solution was not a solution at all. See my comment

Comment: @vks: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't a forum.  I am not at all sure what should be best practice here if you want to *have another go* after posting a trash answer. My first guess is that, if your new solution is substantially different, you should make a new post. Whether you should delete the original or not depends on whether it could be useful to *anybody* in that form

Comment: @mateomiguel: No reflection on what vks has posted, but this is a *horrible* solution that needs to be supported by copious comments. It is hard to believe that Drupal won't let you do this properly. Do you even understand how this regex works yourself?

Comment: @vks: The OP said *"i'm trying to accomplish the exact opposite of this"*. I call that a trash answer

Comment: @vks: You should also explain how your regex pattern works, as it is far from clear

Comment: @Borodin will do that ...why do we need the original post now?to justify ur downvote?

Comment: @vks: Yes, to make sense of that and my comment and the OP's, and your response. Stack Overflow is a *knowledge base*, and the primary purpose of this page is to help other people who come here hoping for a solution to a similar problem. Those people won't have first-hand experience of the flow of comments, and what is obvious to you won't be apparent to them. As I said, it would have been better if you had posted a new solution (since that is what it is). Then it would be up to you whether you wanted to delete the original

Comment: @Borodin Honestly I don't know how the regex works. I was planning to go back and figure it out after this current project is complete. I do understand that the Search404 module in Drupal accepts this regex via an input form on the module configuration page and then plugs it into some php code that searches for matches and replaces them with nothing. I also know that I'm abusing the real purpose of the module by turning what should be a custom search string URL into a new page URL, and that this wouldn't even work without another module, the Redirect module, catching the new page URL.